# H.265 encoding slow on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

OpenCV is so slow on video encoding, like 20 frames per ***minute***, (On 8GB Pi4, 256MB GPU memory, 850MHz GPU Clock, and 2147MHz on CPU Clock)

I think, threading it to one core for taking frames, another one for saving to video will make a better performance but I don't know how I can do it

The code:

```cpp
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    VideoWriter video("outcpp.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('H','V','C','1'), 30, Size(640, 480));
    namedWindow("main");
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (1) {
        cap >> image;
        video.write(image);
        imshow("main", image);
        if ((char)waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;
    }
    cap.release();
}
```

Manjaro ARM, OpenCV with FFMPEG.

*First post, if anything is wrong, kindly write, thanks.*

Comment: How to write multithreaded programs is a very large topic. You might have more luck searching for a tutorial than asking here.

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials, but the problem is, slow on Pi.

Comment: At a guess you are running a debug build, use an optimised build. You might also need to ensure you are using the hardware video encoding supported by your Pi rather than compressing on the CPU

Comment: don't even go there. the issue isn't multithreading. do not give desperate ideas much weight. the issue is that the raspberry pi 4 is SLOW. It's NOT an OpenCV issue. OpenCV uses ffmpeg, which probably does a CPU encode, not using any hardware codecs unless told to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You might also need to ensure you are using the hardware video encoding supported by your Pi rather than compressing on the CPU

Thanks to Alan Birtles, hardware encoding on Pi is way faster than CPU encoding, for who needs, the code (changes are noted in the comment lines):

***Edit: RPi 4 only have OpenMax and MMAL Hardware accel. on FFMpeg, and it looks like OpenCV doesn't supporting them, so, solution is using the cheaper codecs***

````cpp
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    // Video format changed to '.mkv' and FourCC changed to X264
    VideoWriter video("outcpp.mkv", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('X', '2', '6', '4'), 30, Size(640, 480));
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    int i = 0;
    // 'i' variable is only for recording 10 seconds, ignore it
    while (i < 300) {
        i++;
        cap >> image;
        imshow("main", image);
        video.write(image);
    }
    cap.release();
    video.release();
}```
````

Comment: Why I need 2 days for accept my answer, this is the solution for me?

Comment: To point this out: This answer switches from H.265 to H.264. since the backend is ffmpeg, this may still only be encoding on the CPU, without hardware acceleration, but H.264 is a lot cheaper to encode than H.265.

Comment: How to be sore about it uses hardware acceleration? I can not find any result about it?

Comment: Surely you would want to use the hardware GPU for encoding? Try `ffmpeg -hide_banner -encoders | grep -Ei "h264|mjpeg|omx"` and use the one with `omx` in its name.

Comment: There is no "omx". (Maybe because not RPi OS)